# Is there a logical limit to variables in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, caching, memory

I have a script that fetches a JSON object with images URLs from a server via AJAX. The number of image fetched is random and can range from 60 to 300. The script is getting the JSON from the server at a fixed interval.

To prevent network issues, the server returns a base64 of one image at random so the front-end script can store it in a "cache" object. Eventually, the "cache" will fill up with enough material to take over if an AJAX request has failed.

The "cache" also checks how many base64 images it contains before adding a new one. If it reaches its limit, it overwrites the oldest base64, effectively *pruning* the data.

I've installed a monitor application on the machine I was testing with and Chrome hangs after 21 hours or so. That means approximatively 260 AJAX requests, potentially up to 78k images and a "cache" JS object storing 260 images in base64. Is something wrong with my process?

To recap, here's the whole thing:

- Front-end send AJAX request to server
- Server replies with a JSON object filled with images URLs and one JPG in base64
- Front-end creates `<img>` tags with the URLs and stores the base64

  - If the server fails to reply, the front-end use its stored base64 images
- Repeat process to infinity and beyond
- Chrome crashes after 21 hours

Any help appreciated!